# Exporting Google Form Responses into Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage, google-forms

I have a google form setup to submit responses to a Google SQL Database upon submission. I can't seem to figure out how to get the responses off of the form and put them into the strings. Take a look:

```js
var address = 'address';
var user = 'sysImporter';
var userPwd = 'password';
var db = 'db';


var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;


function handleFormSubmit() {
  
 
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  
  var formResponse0 = formResponses[0];
  var formResponse1 = formResponses[1];
  var formResponse2 = formResponses[2];
  var formResponse3 = formResponses[3];
  var formResponse4 = formResponses[4];
  var formResponse5 = formResponses[5];
  
  var itemResponses0 = formResponse0.getItemResponses();
  var itemResponses1 = formResponse1.getItemResponses();
  var itemResponses2 = formResponse2.getItemResponses();
  var itemResponses3 = formResponse3.getItemResponses();
  var itemResponses4 = formResponse4.getItemResponses();
  var itemResponses5 = formResponse5.getItemResponses();
  
  var itemResponse0 = itemResponses0[0];
  var itemResponse1 = itemResponses1[0];
  var itemResponse2 = itemResponses2[0];
  var itemResponse3 = itemResponses3[0];
  var itemResponse4 = itemResponses4[0];
  var itemResponse5 = itemResponses5[0];
  
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO Volunteer '
      + '(FirstName, LastName, PrimaryPhone, SecondaryPhone, VolunteerEmail, Volunteerstatus) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )');
  stmt.setString(1, itemResponse1.getResponse());
  stmt.setString(2, itemResponse2.getResponse());
  stmt.setString(3, itemResponse3.getResponse());
  stmt.setString(4, itemResponse4.getResponse());
  stmt.setString(5, itemResponse0.getResponse());
  stmt.setString(6, itemResponse5.getResponse());
  stmt.execute();
 
  
}
```

The current error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemResponses' of undefined
at handleFormSubmit(Code:24:38)
```

Comment: Are `Libraries` enabled?

Comment: @YaakovBressler, No. No libraries are added. I'm not sure where to the the script ID for any libraries that I might need (i'm guessing I might need formapp libary? cant find the ID). Thanks

Comment: Have you whitelisted IP's? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#using_jdbcgetconnectionurl

Comment: @YaakovBressler Yup, just double checked that the whole list was there

Comment: w e i r d . . .

Comment: [Edit] to provide exact quote of the error.

Comment: Please as @TheMaster suggested print the full error message. Also please indicate which is the line that is failing. Is it when you are executing the query, or before when you try to retrieve the response?
Also, shouldn't you be invoking a method to retrieve the actual response, like [`getResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getresponse). Right now you are feeding the whole `ItemResponse`.

Comment: @Raserhin I've edited the code to something more updated. The error I'm receiving is:

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemResponses' of undefined
    at handleFormSubmit(Code:24:38)

Answer (score 1):

getResponse() retrieves all of the responses for a form, from there you must choose which response you want (in my case the most recent) and dissect it for the answers to the questions, here's what I ended up with:

```js
function handleFormSubmit() {

  //Grab form response list
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  
  //choose most recent response
  var formLastResponse = formResponses.length - 1;
  //grab items from response
  var response = formResponses[formLastResponse];
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  
  //set items to local variables
  var email = response.getRespondentEmail();
  var fname = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var lname = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var primaryphone = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var secondaryphone = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var staus = itemResponses[4].getResponse();
  
  //connect to DB
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  //send SQL Statment to DB
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO Volunteer '
      + '(FirstName, LastName, PrimaryPhone, SecondaryPhone, VolunteerEmail, Volunteerstatus) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )');
  

  stmt.setString(1, fname);
  stmt.setString(2, lname);
  stmt.setString(3, primaryphone);
  stmt.setString(4, secondaryphone);
  stmt.setString(5, email);
  stmt.setString(6, staus);

  stmt.execute();
  
}
```